# dynamically created script src after page load, gives error when initializing function inside said script

Tags: javascript, lightcase.js

I am trying to delay loading for non-critical JS files. It works perfectly for .css files but not for .js files.

For example, I am using lightcase and I am trying to create a `script` link, append `src` and then append it to the `body` as a child, but this way when I have (...).lightcase function in footer it says 'lightcase is not a function'

```js
var phplink = "<?= $config->urls->templates; ?>";
var links = [
  phplink + "swiper/package/css/swiper.min.css",
  phplink + "chunks/psw/dist/photoswipe.min.css",
  phplink + "chunks/psw/dist/default-skin/default-skin.min.css",
  phplink + "chunks/videa/vid.min.css",
  phplink + "chunks/videa/lightcase/src/css/lightcase.min.css",
  phplink + "assets/css/font-awesome.min.css",
  phplink + "chunks/videa/lightcase/src/js/lightcase.min.js",
  phplink + "chunks/videa/lightcase/vendor/jQuery/jquery.events.touch.min.js",
  phplink + "swiper/package/js/swiper.min.js"
];
var types = [
  "css",
  "css",
  "css",
  "css",
  "css",
  "css",
  "js",
  "js",
  "js"
];

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  if (types[i] == "css") {
    var tag = document.createElement("link");
    var attr = document.createAttribute("rel");
    attr.value = "stylesheet";
    tag.setAttributeNode(attr);
    tag.href = links[i];
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(tag);
  } else {
    var tag = document.createElement("script");
    tag.src = links[i];
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(tag);
  }
}
```

I am pretty amateurish with JS, but this works pretty well. I just input the type and link and it works by itself. I am more stoked behind a logic of this. I have all this inside my ready plain javascript function

```js
function ready(fn) {
  if (document.readyState != 'loading') {
    fn();
  } else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
  }
}

let isMobile = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width: 760px)").matches;

ready(function() {
  // here
}
```

Plus right below it is my initilazation script:

```js
$('a[data-rel^=lightcase]').lightcase({
  // stuff
)
};
```

This initilization script cannot reference my lightcase.js referenced in my generating script. I tried putting my `<script>` generating script before `ready(fn)` but the problem still persisted.

How can I you fix this? How can I dynamically load it and still be referenceable?

Comment: As you've tagged the question with jQuery, you can use that to solve your problem. `$.getScript()` will fetch a remote script file when requested and it has a callback to allow you to execute code after that script is available.

Comment: is it possible without  jquery ? i added jquery just because lightcase is jquery, but i dont have jquery in all my project and i want it obe as compatible as possible

Comment: Just because you dynamically created a script element and appended it to the document, does not mean the actual script will be available _immediately_ - the HTTP request to load it, takes time. You will need to make the execution of the code that relies on it, dependent on this script file being done loading somehow. (And strictly speaking not only loading, but the code also needs to be _parsed_, before you can call any functions contained in it.)

Comment: that makes sense but not sure how do i do it, i searched an tried alternative to that .getScript Jquery function but came out empty